Why redirect_uri is needed when client_id is supplied in OAuth?
we know that we need to pass both client_id and redirect_uri in the request. But isn’t that client app already registered its redirect url in authorization server? so that only client_id is needed for the authorization server to look up and retrieve redirect_uri automatically? isn't that only client_id is needed?
